# How can I treat html pages as jsp pages?

Tags: java, html, jsp, session, tomcat

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
Web Server Front-End: IIS 7.5
Web Server Back-End: Tomcat 5.5
AJP Connector is used to pass JSP content from IIS to Tomcat.

I have a number of project folders that get delivered for web consumption every so often. The web pages themselves end with the HTML extension. They need to be hosted on a Tomcat web server and I need session management control via a JSP application. That is, it's not enough for me to check if the session is active for Tomcat. I have some session control specific to the JSP application itself.

I suppose I could run a script which takes the multitude of HTML pages and converts them into JSP, but I'd like to keep things as "drag-and-drop" friendly as I can. I'd rather not make any changes directly to these project folders.

Is there a way I can enforce Tomcat to treat HTML pages as JSP pages? I.e., If, for example, I wanted to include JSP expressions inside the HTML pages, I could do that.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: [See Here][1]

Already been answered.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249622/using-html-files-as-jsps

Answer (score 0):

Jsp pages are similar to html pages they are actually scripts included inside  html pages, they are written in between `<html></html>` tag 
so you can access jsp pages as html
Just save those pages with.html extension

Comment: The same way as we use .php files as html even though we don't use any php scripts in it - yet

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the comment, but that's not what I'm trying to do. The point is I don't want to change the extensions of the project files. I'm trying to find out if there is a way to make Tomcat treat html pages the same as jsp pages, i.e. include jsp expressions inside html pages and tomcat will still be able to read it correctly. Thanks again for your feedback.