# Spring MVC 1 to 1 mapping of a URL to .HTML without exposing path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I am using Spring 4.1.5 with Boot 1.2 on a webservice that does not serve up any JSPs. I don't want to add a JSP servlet but I want it to serve up a single canary page that shows in a prettier html type format the information that would be provided at the `/manage/health` endpoint.

I have a file in `webapp/canary/canary.html` I want to serve this up from the url: `www.mywebservice.com:9343/canary`, exactly like that, NOT canary.html

I tried doing this:

```
@Configuration
public class CanaryConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/canary")
                .addResourceLocations("/canary/canary.html");
    }
}
```

That doesn't work however.

It is expecting the handler to provide a file name. So in otherwords the location should be something like: `/canary/`

and the handler would something like: `/canary/**`

With that, the URL `www.mywebservice.com:9343/canary/canary.html` would work like a charm.

HOWEVER, I want the URL to resolve `www.mywebservice.com:9343/canary` to `webapp/canary/canary.html` without me having to type the html.

This is really easy in a jsp servlet because you can set the suffix ect...

I looked at `ResourceResolver` but it didn't make sense to me how I would link that into my current configuration.

It looks like what I want:

> Provides mechanisms for resolving an incoming request to an actual Resource and for obtaining the public URL path that clients should use when requesting the resource.

See: [ResourceResolver Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceResolver.html)

Any help would be very beneficial.

**Also** I am very aware that I can put html in the resources/static and several other places that are automatically configured. That always requires the .html to be typed, which is not what I want in this case so that won't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use view controllers to do it. Here is a sample of it. Hope this helps.

```
    public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/canary").setViewName("/canary/canary.html");
        }
}
```

Note: if you are using tomcat, you might have to configure jsp servlet to server html files.

[Related post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249622/using-html-files-as-jsps).

Comment: So I had already tried that exact thing, but I guess you need to have it be `registry.addViewController("/canary/").setViewName("/canary/canary.html");`, notice the extra / after canary... that was silly but thank you.

Comment: Also, we are intentionally not using a servlet, this change was done for the purpose of removing the JSP servlet from the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

For information sake, the selected answer is the same as the following:

```
@Controller
public class CanaryController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/canary", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCanary() {
        return "/canary/canary.html";
    }
}
```

The above code will work as long as `canary`(or whatever file/folder) is in your `webapp` folder.

When I tried this I was trying to set the suffix to .html in my YAML (.yml) file and it wasn't working to I thought that it needed to return to a servlet if it is not a RestController. I was mistaken.